# Focus on Textbox works in debug, losing when deploy to a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, focus

I have an asp.net app that I am trying to run on an intranet.  It uses a barcode scanner to scan a badge and then validate the entry. After I scan I set the text back to blank and setup to scan another badge. 
    scanNumber.Text = "";
    scanNumber.Focus();
This works in debug mode on my standalone development PC and it even worked on the virtual test server.  But when we moved it to a physical server and it's own intranet.  It will not send the cursor back to the textbox.  I have to use the mouse to move the cursor into the textbox.
I'm new to C# so I imagine it is something simple.  I've tried a number of ideas from here, but can't find anything that works for me. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the ScriptManager to focus to it instead.

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);

scriptManager.SetFocus(scanNumber);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx for a reference that contains the method.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also worked from within VS, but not once I deployed it.

Comment: What host are you using? If it's azure, remote debug it and make sure the line is being hit and the callback is firing. And have you tried running it in Release mode to see if it also doesn't work in a local environment, and it's an issue of Debug vs Release and not local vs host?